# tar command create directory without 777 permission

Tags: linux, tar, chmod, gzip

I run into an error while extracting a tar file, the created directory are created with the chmod 666 instead of 777. Therefore it will not extract inside this folder.

Here is my command:

```
$umask 000 && tar -xvzf compress.tgz
tar: dist/assets: Cannot mkdir: Permission denied
tar: dist/assets/favicon.ico: Cannot open: Permission denied

$ls -ll
drw-rw-rw- 2 user grp    4096 Mar 14 16:43 assets
```

I used this module on local to compress the file:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/tar

When I create a directory with mkdir it gives 777 mode, what am I missing?

As requested:

```
-bash-4.2$ tar tzvf compress.tgz
drw-rw-rw- 0/0               0 2018-03-15 12:17 dist/
-rw-rw-rw- 0/0           13117 2018-03-15 12:17 dist/3rdpartylicenses.txt
drw-rw-rw- 0/0               0 2018-03-15 12:17 dist/assets/
```

I use `--strip 1` to extract.

Comment: you never, ever, ever need to have 777 rights.

Comment: @thebtm let's say I have a folder with one file inside dist/assets/favicon.ico. When extracting I got only one folder dist with 666 mode and nothing inside. Also it output the errors above.

Comment: `tar` does have a `p` flag to preserve permissions however poor they may be

Comment: @Carpette never say never. I can think of several scenarios where 777 is an appropriate permission mode.

Comment: Please add to your question the output of first few lines of `tar tzvf compress.tgz`. It would be worth checking the permissions within the archive itself.

Comment: Are you running this as root (in any way, including via `sudo` or `su`), or as an ordinary non-root user?

Comment: @roaima I do not have root access but I can mkdir manually

Comment: Since can manually and successfully `mkdir assets`, what if you `tar -xvfz ... && chmod -R 777 dist`?

Comment: @RonJohn during the tar it create the subfolder but they haven't the right chmod so the subfolder and subfiles aren't created.

Comment: What implementation/version of tar is it? Neither GNU tar (1.29) nor bsdtar (3.2.2) nor star (1.5.3) have any issue with that on my system. They do recreate the directory structure with the broken permissions OK. Is it possible that you have a `umask 222` for instance (with which bsdtar but not GNU tar fails for me)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the output of `tar tv` the permissions in the archive itself are broken. If you have any control over the tool that created this archive I would strongly recommend that you fix it, or report a bug.

I assume you still need to extract the files from the broken archive. Try this:

```
tar xzvf compress.tgz --delay-directory-restore
find dist -type d -exec chmod a+x {} \;
```

(We can't use a trailing `+` in this instance because the `chmod` must be applied one directory at time so that `find` can descend into the fixed subdirectories. The semicolon is prefixed with a backslash so that it's not treated by the shell as a special character, but rather it's passed to the `find... -exec` as a literal.)

Comment: -bash-4.2$ find dist -type d -exec chmod a+x {} +

find: 'dist/assets': Permission denied

Comment: @Frenentix please change the trailing `+` to `\;`. I'll update my question too

Answer (score 0):

With `star` (from `schily-tools`), you can extract it  with:

```
star xf file.tgz -no-p -find -type d -chmod a+x
```

To add the execute permission (for everybody) to the extracted directories to fix those bogus permissions in the archive.

With `-no-p`, the `umask` is also applied even if run as root, which assuming your `umask` is at least 002 would also fix those too wide write permissions (note that the `umask` takes precedence over the `-chmod`).

Note that none of the GNU `tar`, `bsdtar` nor `star` implementations of `tar` in my test have any issue extracting an archive with such broken permissions. Most likely here, you're trying to extract it while there was **already** a `dist` directory without search permission (because for instance you have extracted a similar archive with similarly broken permissions).

You'd need to fix those permissions first before extracting the archive.

Comment: You are correct, any decent modern tar implementation implements automated delayed directory setup for permissions and time stamps. When a directory is newly created during extraction, this is done with sane permissions and the permissions from the archive are applied later.